# INSERT a row which contains a calculated columns base on the same row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like the following within a **single** SQL statement:

Assume we have a table with 3 simple string (varchar) columns; col1, col2 and col3.

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) VALUES ('super', 'cool', [col1] + [col2])
```

This fails with 2 error messages, the first being: `Invalid column name 'col1'.`

I would like to know if this is possible without having to repeat the values from col1 and col2, ie:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) VALUES ('super', 'cool', 'super' + 'cool')
```

I am messing around with SQL Server 2016.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select from `VALUES` table constructor

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) 
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.a + t.b
FROM (VALUES ('super', 'cool')) t(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, which allows you to use a sum of columns as the source value:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([col1], [col2], [col3])
SELECT 'super', 'cool', [col1] + [col2]
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks, but have you tried this? Maybe I am doing something wrong, but it doesn't work for me. I am still getting the same errors as before.

Comment: @munyul Sorry...I left out the `FROM` clause, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks again, however it still does not seem to work. I no longer get an error message, but nothing is inserted. The table remains empty.

Comment: @munyul The above insert should _double_ the number of records in your table, period.  If it does not, then maybe your table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure You can do this within a single statement.

The easiest way is to use variables:

```
declare @col1 AS varchar(10) = 'super'
declare @col2 AS varchar(10) = 'cool'


INSERT INTO mytable ([col1], [col2], [col3]) VALUES (@col1, @col2, @col1 + @col2)
```